# Dynamically decide google API_KEY for google-map

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I am working on an app which shows shop-location using google-map. I need to specify google-Geo API_KEY in manifest to use the map. The map is working fine but I want to dynamically decide the API_KEY used for google-map.

I have searched for such implementation or similar-question but haven't found any solution.

Just want to know for sure, is it possible to dynamically select/use google API_KEY? And How?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Google API V2. As the documentation reads

> The API key has to be assigned using the Manifest file

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application

But its possible for `MapView`. Google Docs

> If you are instantiating a MapView directly from code, you should pass the Maps API Key in the MapView constructor.

code snippet:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(.....) {
         super.onCreate(....);
         mMapView = new MapView(this, YOUR_MAP_API_KEY); //pass key to MapView Constructor here
         setContentView(mMapView);
      //   ....
    }
```